# DML trigger to keep cross reference-tables in sync for INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have good experience with T-SQL and SQL-Server, but have never worked with DML triggers.

I need help for the following scenario for an INSERT trigger.

This question is related to a mobile-device application, and we need to limit the data-flow to the mobile-device for performance considerations.

I have employees (as a DRIVER) and vehicles that take TRIPS -- multiple per day and hundreds of employee drivers.  As each trip is "started" the trip is INSERTed into the TRIP-table. The TRIP-table contains fields for UID_TRIP, UID-DRIVER and UID_VEHICLE along with other fields.

I have two cross-reference tables ...
XREF_TRIP_DRIVER with TWO fields UID_TRIP and UID_DRIVER (being UNIQUE in this table)
XREF_TRIP_VEHICLE with TWO fields UID_TRIP and UID_VEHICLE (being UNIQUE in this table).

This is to have a single record for each UID_DRIVER and each UID_VEHICLE --each containing either the same or different UID_TRIP -- essentially the "current" or "most recent" trip.  These xref-tables are relatively small -- containing a few hundred records and show only a single TRIP (UID) for the UID_DRIVER and the UID_VEHICLE.

For the TRIP-INSERT-operation (meaning a new TRIP-record is INSERTed into the TRIP-table, I'd like to place the key-fields into both of these XREF tables using the DML-INSERT-TRIGGER "after" the trip-insert has been added to the DB.  The new UID_TRIP needs to be updated in each of the XREF-tables.

When a new trip is started, the UID_DRIVER would cause the XREF_TRIP_DRIVER-table to be updated with the new/different UID_TRIP value -or- a new trip is started the UID_VEHICLE would cause the XREF-TRIP_VEHICLE-table to be updated with a new/different UID_TRIP value.

Can there be a trigger t-sql code example of doing what I described above?
Thank you.

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**  To provide you with the use-case to the overall business rules, a Trip is "started" in a vehicle (UID_VEHICLE) driven by a driver (UID_DRIVER) when the driver enters some data into a mobile screen and then clicks the START button. This sends the screen-data to the server and to the database. This creates a new DB TRIP-record, and I thought, the INSERT-trigger would record the UID_TRIP and UID_DRIVER to the XREF_TRIP_DRIVER-table by "finding" the UID_DRIVER and "replacing"/UPDATE UID_TRIP with the new UID_TRIP.  This saves the current/most-recent UID_TRIP for this UID_DRIVER.  Similarly, for the XREF_TRIP_VEHICLE-table.

The trip's arrival is saved in the TRIP-table and remains in the XREF-tables until the next trip starts for the DRIVER or for the VEHICLE.

There are no other triggers needed since there is no way to DELETE a trip from the business rules.  Updates of the time-stamps for the trip (start DTTM and arrival DTTM and other information) are "updated" from the mobile-screens as the trip progresses from "start" to "arrival".  The XREF-tables only retain the current trip until another trip takes its place.

The business rules are complex when the driver logs into the mobile-screens -- dealing with the inspections needed before a trip starts and at the end of the "shift" for that driver or for that vehicle. So, these complex considerations require "finding" the most recent trip for a driver and for a vehicle.  That is why the XREF-tables only hold one trip for each DRIVER and VEHICLE.  So when the driver logs-in, a number of data-fetches are made for the most recent trip for a vehicle and for the driver to determine whether the pre-trip inspection has been made and whether the post-trip inspection has been made.

I determined it was "cheaper" to save these values in these "small" XREF-tables rather than have a number of queries fetch the most recent trip from many thousands of records to select the most recent trip.

Comment: Instead of describing what your tables look like, please show the `CREATE TABLE` definitions, and show expected results. Do you need an `INSERT` `UPDATE` or `DELETE` trigger, or all three? What do you want to happen if a Trip is deleted or moved earlier than another Trip?

Comment: WOW...thank you for your reply. Amazing me with how fast you coded this solution.  To provide you with a narrowing use-case for the overall business rules, please refer to the original question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to get rid of these tables, and just use a view instead.

```sql
CREATE VIEW XREF_TRIP_DRIVER 
AS
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_DRIVER ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM TRIP
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

And the same for the other table

```sql
CREATE VIEW XREF_TRIP_VEHICLE
AS
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_VEHICLE ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM TRIP
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

---

Having said that, if you really want an actual table, you can write a trigger like this. Note that you need to handle multiple or zero rows in the `inserted` table.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER MostRecentTrip
ON dbo.Trip
AFTER INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE x
SET UID_TRIP = i.UID_TRIP
FROM XREF_TRIP_DRIVER x
JOIN (
    SELECT i.*,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_DRIVER ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM inserted i
) i ON i.UID_DRIVER = x.UID_DRIVER
WHERE i.rn = 1;

INSERT XREF_TRIP_DRIVER
  (UID_DRIVER, UID_TRIP)
SELECT i.UID_DRIVER, i.UID_TRIP
FROM (
    SELECT i.*,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_DRIVER ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM inserted i
) i
WHERE i.rn = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM XREF_TRIP_DRIVER other
    WHERE other.UID_DRIVER = i.UID_DRIVER
);

UPDATE x
SET UID_TRIP = i.UID_TRIP
FROM XREF_TRIP_VEHICLE x
JOIN (
    SELECT i.*,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_VEHICLE ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM inserted i
) i ON i.UID_VEHICLE = x.UID_VEHICLE
WHERE i.rn = 1;

INSERT XREF_TRIP_VEHICLE
  (UID_VEHICLE, UID_TRIP)
SELECT i.UID_VEHICLE, i.UID_TRIP
FROM (
    SELECT i.*,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.UID_VEHICLE ORDER BY i.DATE DESC)
    FROM inserted i
) i
WHERE i.rn = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM XREF_TRIP_DRIVER other
    WHERE other.UID_VEHICLE = i.UID_VEHICLE
);
```

This does not deal with updates and deletes, which would require going back to the base table to get the new latest value.

Comment: Thank you, Charlie... for your response and I selected your response as the answer.  Thank you for being so smart and so quick with your response.  :-)